# Unable to get an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a custom select but I get stuck when I want to change the text of what is displaying.
Probably an idiot problem or just me being blind but I don't get why is it returning me this.

Have a look a this fiddle : -> **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/h9zs62da/6/)**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null(…)

But actually the thing I am clicking on is completely define since it is a li element.
I tried to target it by id or class but I have the same error, tried to use each, style the same problem I clearly don't know anymore where this is coming from.

This is the code I'm using.

```
$('.custom-select').click(function(){
    $('.customSelect').toggle();
});
$(document).on('click','li',function(){
    $(".custom-select").text() = $(this).text();
});
```

I you guys have any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.custom-select').click(function () {
        $('.customSelect').toggle();
    });
    $(document).on('click', 'li', function () {
        $(".custom-select").text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Please take a look at this and see.

If you want to hide the list after selecting, then add the below code at the end of `$(document).on(function(){`

```
$('.customSelect').toggle();
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jerintk/h9zs62da/8/)

Comment: Ok Im feeling ashamed of my self a bit. Still do you know why the other solution does not work ?

Comment: @Baldráni: Albert Eintsien once said: “Everybody is a genius. But if you judge a fish by its ability to climb a tree, it will live its whole life believing that it is stupid.” So don't be ashamed to ask questions, me too have so many... In jquery, .text() is a function. and it'll accept arguments. But you can't assign values to function like what you did. What I did is, the text value is passed as the argument. Hope you got my simple explanation... For more detail, http://api.jquery.com/text/